# How to access nested dependencies at compilation time?

Tags: java, gradle, compilation, dependencies

I have developed two libs: `cms-lib` and `common-lib`.

`cms-lib` is dependant on `common-lib` like this

```
# gradle.build of cms-lib

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.example.shared:common-lib:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

`common-lib` contains some public classes - f.e. `com.example.shared.common.Content.java`

The idea is that `cms-lib` is for third-party customer use (they should declare it in its gradle dependencies), while `common-lib` should be hidden from the customer (customer does not have to declare its gradle dependencies). So they just declare only `cms-lib`  - like this:

```
# A
# build.gradle of a consumer of `cms-lib`

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.example.shared:cms-lib:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

That means that `common-lib` is nested the dependency of `cms-lib`.

I expect that public classes from the nested dependency `common-lib`, can be accessed by a customer of `cms-lib`. But it turns out they do not accessible as I get the compilation error:

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED
C:\temp\lib-test\src\main\java\consumer\Controller.java:3: error: package com.example.shared.common does not exist
import com.example.shared.common.Content;
```

It seems that in this case, public classes of `support-lib` is not available in compilation time (probably only at Runtime).

How to access nested dependencies at compilation time?

Comment: A transitive dependency does not mean the dependency is included in the top level jar - `common-lib` has to be somewhere on the classpath to compile (and run).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to apply the `java-library` to the `cms-lib` project. Then you'll need to define `common-lib` in the `api` configuration in order for it to be available on the classpath of a consumer of `cms-lib`

You can read more about `api` vs `implementation` in the docs for the [Java library plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html).

```
# gradle.build of cms-lib

dependencies {
  api 'com.example.shared:common-lib:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}


# A
# build.gradle of a consumer of `cms-lib`

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.example.shared:cms-lib:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Comment: Only `java-library` plugin, not `java-library-plugin`

Comment: Thank you! This solution is what I was looking for. It really helped me.